# Clickable Tinder Cards SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, view, swiftui

I'm trying to create a swipeable shopping app prototype and came across a problem that I simply can't figure out.

**My goal is to make each card clickable, so that when a user taps on one of them, it shows them another view with more product details**

I've already made the cards swipeable, and i've already made each card clickable.

I am unable to figure out how to update the information in product view so that it matches with the clicked card

```
struct ContentView: View {
// MARK: - PROPERTIES

@EnvironmentObject var shop: Shop

@State var showLiked: Bool = false
@State var showBag: Bool = false

@GestureState private var dragState = DragState.inactive
private let dragAreaThreshold: CGFloat = 65.0
@State private var lastCardIndex: Int = 1
@State private var cardRemovalTransition = AnyTransition.trailingBotton

// MARK: - CARD VIEWS

@State var cardViews: [CardView] = {
    var views = [CardView]()
    for index in 0..<2 {
        views.append(CardView(zoope: zoopeData[index]))
    }
    return views
}()

// MARK: - MOVE THE CARD

private func moveCards() {
    cardViews.removeFirst()
    
    self.lastCardIndex += 1
    
    let zoope = zoopeData[lastCardIndex % zoopeData.count]
    
    let newCardView = CardView(zoope: zoope)
    
    cardViews.append(newCardView)
}

// MARK: - TOP CARD

private func isTopCard(cardView: CardView) -> Bool {
    guard let index = cardViews.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == cardView.id }) else {
        return false
    }
    return index == 0
}

// MARK: - DRAG STATE

enum DragState {
    case inactive
    case pressing
    case dragging(translation: CGSize)
    
    var translation: CGSize {
        switch self {
        case .inactive, .pressing:
            return .zero
        case .dragging(let translation):
            return translation
        }
    }
    
    var isDragging: Bool {
        switch self {
        case .dragging:
            return true
        case .pressing, .inactive:
            return false
        }
    }
    
    var isPressing: Bool {
        switch self {
        case .pressing, .dragging:
            return true
        case .inactive:
            return false
        }
    }
}

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        if shop.showingProduct == false && shop.selectedProduct == nil {
            ZStack {
            Color("ColorBackground")
                .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .all)
            VStack {
                // MARK: - HEADER
                HeaderView()

                Spacer()
                
                // MARK: - CARDS
                ZStack {                        
                    ForEach(cardViews) { cardView in
                        cardView
                            .zIndex(self.isTopCard(cardView: cardView) ? 1 : 0)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                shop.selectedProduct = sampleClothes
                                shop.showingProduct = true
                            }
                            .overlay(
                                ZStack {
                                    // X-MARK SYMBOL
                                    Image(systemName: "x.circle")
                                        .modifier(SymbolModifier())
                                        .opacity(self.dragState.translation.width < -self.dragAreaThreshold && self.isTopCard(cardView: cardView) ? 1.0 : 0.0)
                                    
                                    // HEART SYMBOL
                                    Image(systemName: "heart.circle")
                                        .modifier(SymbolModifier())
                                        .opacity(self.dragState.translation.width > self.dragAreaThreshold && self.isTopCard(cardView: cardView) ? 1.0 : 0.0)
                                }
                            )
                            
                            .offset(x: self.isTopCard(cardView: cardView) ? self.dragState.translation.width : 0, y: self.isTopCard(cardView: cardView) ? self.dragState.translation.height : 0)
                            .scaleEffect(self.dragState.isDragging && self.isTopCard(cardView: cardView) ? 0.85 : 1.0)
                            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: self.isTopCard(cardView: cardView) ? Double(self.dragState.translation.width / 12) : 0))
                            .animation(.interpolatingSpring(stiffness: 120, damping: 120))
                            .gesture(LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.01)
                                        .sequenced(before: DragGesture())
                                        .updating(self.$dragState, body: { (value, state, transaction) in
                                            switch value {
                                            case .first(true):
                                                state = .pressing
                                            case .second(true, let drag):
                                                state = .dragging(translation: drag?.translation ?? .zero)
                                            default:
                                                break
                                            }
                                        })
                                        .onChanged({ (value) in
                                            guard case .second(true ,let drag?) = value else {
                                                return
                                            }
                                            
                                            if drag.translation.width < -self.dragAreaThreshold {
                                                self.cardRemovalTransition = .leadingBottom
                                            }
                                            
                                            if drag.translation.width > self.dragAreaThreshold {
                                                self.cardRemovalTransition = .trailingBotton
                                            }
                                        })
                                        .onEnded({ (value) in
                                            guard case .second(true, let drag?) = value else {
                                                return
                                            }
                                            
                                            if drag.translation.width < -self.dragAreaThreshold || drag.translation.width > self.dragAreaThreshold {
                                                self.moveCards()
                                            }
                                        })
                            ).transition(self.cardRemovalTransition)
                    }
                }
                .padding()
                
                Spacer()
                
                // MARK: - FOOTER
                FooterView(showLikedView: $showLiked, showBagView: $showBag)
                    .opacity(dragState.isDragging ? 0.0 : 1.0)
                    .animation(.default)
            }
                
            }
        } else {
            ProductDetailView()
        }
    }
}
```

}

The problem lies in `shop.selectedProduct = sampleClothes`

I can't use `cardView` as they are different data types.

**Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated, as I have tried literally everything I could think of over the past 3 days to solve this.**

*P.S- i can provide more code if needed. apologies for the long pasted code*

***Edit: Shop & sampleClothes**

```
class Shop: ObservableObject {
   @Published var showingProduct: Bool = false
   @Published var selectedProduct: Clothes?
}

let sampleClothes: Clothes = zoopeData[0]
```

Clothes is a custom data type with product info (images, price, name, etc.)

Comment: You aren't showing the code for `Shop` or for `sampleClothes`. There's no way to diagnose any of this without knowing the types. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @jnpdx just updated it!

Comment: Sorry -- at least for me, there's just too much to dig through and it doesn't compile because you've left out so much stuff. If you can come up with a reproducible example, it would really help.

Comment: @jnpdx no worries, i managed to find a solution :) i still appreciate you having a look!